# Is this a valid proof of Euler's product formula for the totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, totient-function, primitive-roots

I will attempt the proof using induction. But first, a lemma:

**Lemma 1:** If $ n = p^{\alpha} $, where $ p $ is prime and $ \alpha\in\mathbb{N} $, then $ \phi(n) = n(1-\frac{1}{p}) $.

$ \underline{Proof} $: We wish to count the number of numbers from 1 to $ n $ that are coprime with $ n $. We can do this by taking $ n $ and subtracting off the ones that *aren't* coprime with $ n $. The ones that aren't are the mutiples of $ p $, namely $ p, 2p, 3p, \dots, n-p $. How many multiples of $ p $ go into $ n $? Precisely $ \frac{n}{p} $. We therefore have

$ \phi(n) = n - \frac{n}{p} = n(1-\frac{1}{p}) $, as required. $ \hspace{9.5cm} \square $

Lemma 1 tells us that the formula for $ \phi(n) $ is invariant under any prime factors of $ n $ having powers. Therefore, it suffices to prove the formula for when $ n $ consists only of distinct factors. So suppose that $ n $ is composite with prime factorization $ n = p_{1}p_{2}\dots{p_{r}} $, where $ r\in\mathbb{N} $ and each factor is distinct. Then $ \phi(n) = n\prod\limits_{i=1}^{r}(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}) $.

$ \underline{Proof} $: For $ S(1) $:
$ n = p_{1} \Longrightarrow \phi(n) = p_{1} - 1 = p_{1}(1-\frac{1}{p_{1}}) = n(1-\frac{1}{p_{1}}) $. Therefore true for $ S(1) $.

Assume true for $ S(k) $, for some $ k\in\mathbb{N} $.

For $ S(k+1) $: The value of $ \phi(n) $ is equal to the number of primitive $ n $-th roots of unity. That is, the primitive roots of the equation $ z^{n} - 1 = 0 \Longrightarrow (z^{p_{k+1}})^{m} = 1 $, where $ m = p_{1}\dots{p_{k}} $.

Using $ S(k) $, there are $ m\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}) $ primitive $ m $-th roots of unity in the variable $ z^{p_{k+1}} $. Let $ \omega $ be one of these roots. Then we have $ z^{p_{k+1}} = \omega \Longrightarrow \Big(\frac{z}{\omega^{\frac{1}{p_{k+1}}}}\Big)^{p_{k+1}} = 1 $. Since $ p_{k+1} $ is prime, there are precisely $ p_{k+1}-1 $ primitive solutions for $ \frac{z}{\omega^{\frac{1}{p_{k+1}}}} $ and hence for $ z $. And this occurs for each of the $ m\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}) $ possible choices of $ \omega $. Therefore, we multiply the former with the latter to find the total number of primitive roots, giving

$ \phi(n) = (p_{k+1}-1)\cdot m\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k}(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}) = mp_{k+1}\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}) = n\prod\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}(1-\frac{1}{p_{i}}) $.

Therefore true for $ S(k+1) $, and hence this is true for all of $ r \in\mathbb{N}. \hspace{5cm} \square $

Is my proof correct?

Comment: It would be reasonable if you'd write what you're trying to prove at the very beginning of the post...Function's aren't provable. And such a proof by induction in this case should be, imo, on the number of prime divisors of $\;n\;$ (or of **different** prime divisors), not induction on $\;n\;$ ...

Comment: What I meant was that I was attempting to prove the formula for the function. Sorry if that wasn't clear. And I was doing induction on $ r $, not $ n $, which *is* the number of divisors.

Comment: "Lemma 1 tells us that the formula for $ϕ(n)$ is invariant under any prime factors of $n$ having powers." What does it mean and why?

Comment: That was meant to mean that the formula is the same regardless of the value of $ \alpha $, since $ \alpha $ does not appear in the expression for $ \phi(n) $.

Comment: It is not yet a reason to expect that $\alpha$ will not appear if some other prime divisors of $n$ are present.

Comment: Ok, fair enough.

Comment: It must always be stated over what is induction going to be carried on, in particular if there are several different natural numbers involved. Define also what is $\;S\;$ ...